# Inconsistent user experience when browsing by tag in the Android app

Tags: bug, tags, android-app, user-experience

Browsing a StackExchange site's tags in the Android app (`Version 1.0.85`) appears to be inconsistent.

Clicking on a tag in a question and navigating back will bring the user back to the screen they were on before - which is the expected behavior. Clicking on a tag from the tags view in the action bar, opening a question, and navigating back does not. It brings the user back to the list of tags rather than the results with that tag.

[Visualization](https://zippy.gfycat.com/OccasionalDecentBorderterrier.webm) (Gfycat)